# Leadfoot bypass IE certificate warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, intern

I'm trying to execute javascript in the browser of the client on which my intern/selenium/leadfoot tests are running. Specifically, I'm trying to bypass IE8 & 9 certificate warning.

Previously, using selenium-python bindings I could use this code to run on all browsers, passing the warning if it occurred:

```
if "Certificate" in driver.title:
    driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();")
```

Now using leadfoot, I've tried many combinations of the following:

```
.get(require.toUrl('https://secure-url.com')
.execute("document.getElementById('overridelink').click();")
// OR
.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();")
```

But cannot get this javascript to execute on the client. Has anyone had success with this?

```
.execute('alert("hello");')
```

works fine on other pages, but not this page. It's as if leadfoot is not able to run JS in this security page, but selenium api is?

Eventually it fails with the error:

```
JavaScriptError: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/1fa8a4a3-8774-46af-ad87-0e8fbc5a1388/execute / {"script":"document.getElementById('overridelink').click();","args":[]}] JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds

Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'

System info: host: 'IE9Win7', ip: '169.254.0.207', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'

Session ID: 8b20796a-1d40-48ad-82e1-25ce16a40f17

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:29797/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]

  at Server._post  <node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\Server.js:68:9>
...
```

Also, I can confirm in WebDriverIO I can bypass the warning with:

```
client.url("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();")
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It gives a timeout error for the following ```.find()``` statement, seems to be executing in the wrong context.

Comment: It would be good to show that find statement in your question, together with the exact error message you are getting. Also, did you check the console on the browser to see if there is any error there?

Comment: Updated with error, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully navigate through the Certificate Error page by sending keys to tab through the page to the override link and enter like so:

```
.pressKeys([Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.ENTER])
```

Obviously there may be a better way but this works.

Example:

```
        var command = this.remote;
        return command
            .get(require.toUrl('https://portal-stg.vpc.locusdev.net'))
            .getPageTitle()

            // IE Certificate Error Workaround
            .then(function(title) {
                if (title.indexOf('Certificate Error') !== -1) {
                    command.pressKeys([Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.ENTER])
                }
                return true;
            })
```